# Environment variables in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, environment-variables, windows-phone-8.1

I'm new to Windows Phone 8.1 and I'm looking for a way to store some data as application variables that I can reach from all over the app. Is there a LocalStorage or IsolatedStorage in Windows Phone 8.1 ?
I've heard about Windows.Storage namespace where I can find **LocalSettings** or **RoamingSettings** but I don't know if I can store in it some lists or either some dictionnaries... I can also create a GlobalVariables static class where I could initiate some variables and add it app.xaml.cs but I believe that the WP 8.1 framework contains something more proper to satisfy such a need. Could someone give me some guidelines ?

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-22-Storing-and-Retrieving-Serialized-Data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of variables you are willing to save.
If you don't want to store your variables between application usages, you can simply have a GlobalVariables static class and it will do no harm.

However, if you are looking to store information across different usages (or even devices of the same user) you can use LocalSettings:

- These are meant to be used only in one device.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx

- Or RoamingSettings, if you want a user to access those variables in the same aplication but from different devices logged in with the same Windows Account.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700362.aspx

However you can always look at this page for some general knowledge on this subject:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465099.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that complete answer !